# Get name of users(persons, not applications) in linux system using psutil library

Tags: python, linux, psutil

I am trying to use psutil library to get users logged in to linux system.

For that i used function psutil.users()

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.users()
[suser(name='vibhcool', terminal='tty2',host='localhost',started=1473815296.0)]
```

I want to extract the username from this list, what shall i do?
Also what is suser here?

Comment: From the documentation: `Return users currently connected on the system as a list of namedtuples` https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.users

Comment: Is there a function to return all users on the system? And what is 'suser'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why they choose the name `suser`, but it's actually a namedtuple.

That shouldn't matter, you get the name of a user like so:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> users = psutil.users()
>>> first_user = users[0]
>>> name = first_user.name
>>> print(name)
'vibhcool'
```

In short:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> print(psutil.users()[0].name)
'vibhcool'
```

Comment: why call it multiple times?  Just do:`users = psutil.users()    first_user=users[0]`   ?  Ugh, terrible formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, (sorry i am bad at googling)

psutil.users() outputs a list, so it can be traversed using for loop

```
users = psutil.users()
    for user in users:
        print(user.name)
```

reference: http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/53877/psutil.users

Answer (score 0):

Isnt the much safe thing to do but:

```
users_name = [user[0] for user in psutil.users()]
```